# Regex to extract multiple fields from multiple pattern of data

Tags: regex

I have to extract multiple fields from data. Some times data pattern is slightly different so I want that it should work with all those patterns.

I have written regex but its not perfect.

My regex is saved at:
https://regex101.com/r/V1gWZW/1

Here is the fields which I am looking to extract.

[image]

PS: Regex is not specific to any language. I will use it in Splunk Tool.

Comment: The [Splunk regex syntax](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.3/SearchReference/Regex) appears to be roughly Perl-compatible.

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained. It's not at all clear from your link which patterns you expect to match which parts.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/V1gWZW/2

Comment: I have removed few fields but its not extracting the correct fields. For better understanding refer the attached picture. I have mentioned each field I want to extract.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by myself.

final working regex:
https://regex101.com/r/V1gWZW/4

```
((?P<TIME_GC_TIMESTAMP>[^ ]*?):\s*)?(?P<relative_time>\d+\.\d+):.*(?P<Name>ParNew|P.*ParNew|PSYoungGen|DefNew):?\s?(?P<ParNew_before_1>\d+)K->(?P<ParNew_after_1>\d+)K\((?P<young_heap_size>\d+)K\)]?\s?(?P<ParNew_before_2>\d+)K\->(?P<ParNew_after_2>\d+)K\((?P<total_heap_size>\d+)K\),\s*(?P<par_new_duration>\d+\.\d+) secs\]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please insert your regex here, not only via a link. Quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer : "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline". Except for that - great Q & A

Comment: Agreed !! thanks for suggestion. Added final regex in answer.